# Should we write information already in the tag in the body of our questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just reading [What is the purpose of [64-bit] and [32-bit]?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/11175/465600) made me think...

**Should we include information in tags in the body of our text?**

Tags like the question still get people to comment whether they are using 32bit or 64bit. So should we still add more to the question by adding this to the end of our questions for readers who don't look at tags?

Comment: Yes, the tags are for categorisation and cataloguing, your question body should contain *all* relevant information .

Comment: The tags `32-bit` and `64-bit` should be for questions that are specifically about the bitness of something. They shouldn't be placed on every question that uses the 32 or 64 bit version of a software.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Care to chime in on the [64-bit question](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11175/465600)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost certainly yes. While tags are useful for searchability, at the end of the day they're no replacement for attempting to describe your environment. In addition, not everyone reads the tags at first (I often don't) and having it in the question body improves readability.

Comment: Correct, it is very 'easy' to overlook the tags when reading the question.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, most of the time we should. As I see it:

- The header describes the problem briefly.
- The body contains **all** information, if possible including what was already tried and preferably **one** question.
- The tags are useful for searching and should have key items.

Comment: @Henness - You forgot one key part.  The body of the question should actually contain a question.  Many times people just use the title as the actual question, because it happens to be a question, but the title should describe the question not be the actual "question" the author has.

Comment: Quite true. And rather a <censored> for people as me who often skip the title. Will add.